# Search input field to search JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Array of objects which i am generating on the basis of user requirement.

**What I am trying to do is:-**

1. I have a Array of objectswhich I have stored in a variable and have an input field
2. input field is type search, so in my Array of objects the keys are `ItemName`,`BatchCode`,`CasesQty`,`UnitQty`,`PurRate` and `Disc%` i am taking `ItemName` as the search parameter
3. Now what I am doing whenever user focusing in input field I am searching the data as for `ItemName`, but somehow I am not able to create what I have to
4. I want to create something like [image: This]
5. Whenever user types inside the input field matching item should come inside input field also
6. the dropdowns which are coming as search parameters in my code are not clickable

**My code**

```js
var data = [{
    "ItemName": "Curd",
    "BatchCode": 400231,
    "CasesQty": 10,
    "UnitQty": 5,
    "PurRate": 50,
    "Disc%": 6
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Rice",
    "BatchCode": 400123,
    "CasesQty": 12,
    "UnitQty": 7,
    "PurRate": 80,
    "Disc%": 10
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Milk",
    "BatchCode": 400156,
    "CasesQty": 4,
    "UnitQty": 2,
    "PurRate": 20,
    "Disc%": 2
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Butter",
    "BatchCode": 400564,
    "CasesQty": 8,
    "UnitQty": 6,
    "PurRate": 35,
    "Disc%": 4
  }
]

$('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
  var searchField = $(this).val();
  if (searchField === '') {
    $('#filter-records').html('');
    return;
  }

  var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  var output = '<div class="row">';

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if ((val.ItemName.search(regex) != -1)) {
      output += '<div">';
      output += '<div class="form-group"><a class="dropdown-item">' + val.ItemName + '</a></div>'

    }
  });
  output += '</div>';
  $('#filter-records').html(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="search" class="form-control" name="searchInput" id="searchInput">
</div>

<div id="filter-records"></div>
```

I think I am using the Wrong approach to display search parameters in new div, The image I have uploaded I want to do something like that

Comment: You have an array of objects, not a Json string.

Comment: How about jquery UI autocomplete?

Comment: @Pradeep actually i don't want to use any library,but if it can be done like what i am trying to achieve then no problem

Comment: This is just an idea, You can do something like use a dropdown initially populate it with an empty array then on change event, give setTimeout of 1 sec, At that time fill the array with item names that correspond to the entered string and give it t dropdown

Comment: @DeepankarSingh No that can be very complicated, i have tried input field with drop-down,in drop-down i have populated all the `ItemName` and also provided a search box inside dropdown to search, but is against the user requirement, i want to create Something like i have uploaded a Image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first create list of item name from given object, then use auto complete library. I am using jQuery library for autocomplete.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var data = [{
      "ItemName": "Curd",
      "BatchCode": 400231,
      "CasesQty": 10,
      "UnitQty": 5,
      "PurRate": 50,
      "Disc%": 6
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Rice",
      "BatchCode": 400123,
      "CasesQty": 12,
      "UnitQty": 7,
      "PurRate": 80,
      "Disc%": 10
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Milk",
      "BatchCode": 400156,
      "CasesQty": 4,
      "UnitQty": 2,
      "PurRate": 20,
      "Disc%": 2
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Butter",
      "BatchCode": 400564,
      "CasesQty": 8,
      "UnitQty": 6,
      "PurRate": 35,
      "Disc%": 4
    }
  ]

    let itemName = data.map(value => { return value.ItemName });
    
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: itemName
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey cant we do like what i am typing the matching text should also come inside the text field

Comment: can't understand ! which text field ? if you are looking for text field, then it not possible because text-field can hold one value only. 
actually m not understand your real problem, i think.

Comment: suppose i am typing `curd` so when i type cu then curd should gets populated inside input field,as the nearest matched value from drop-down, like in my image i have typed `c` the closest value to `c` gets populated